# How to nearGeoPoint location from Parse array?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nsarray, cllocation

I'm trying to use the whereKey, nearGeoPoint. The only problem is my location is in an array of locations. How would I get a single location from this array? Here is my code below...

```
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        postQuery.whereKey("locations", nearGeoPoint: PFGeoPoint(latitude: locations[0].coordinate.latitude, longitude: locations[0].coordinate.longitude), withinMiles: 30)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the CLLocationManagerDelegate:

> This array always contains at least one object representing the current location. If updates were deferred or if multiple locations arrived before they could be delivered, the array may contain additional entries. The objects in the array are organized in the order in which they occurred. Therefore, the most recent location update is at the end of the array.

If you want to send the most recent location to Parse you should use `locations.last`

Comment: Thanks. But I'm trying to find a way to whereKey a certain location from a Parse array. Is it possible? And if so how would I do it?

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question. I think to get an answer from somebody you should describe your issue a bit better. Do you want to get a single location from a Parse object, that has an array of locations as a key? What do you want to be the result of your query? Normally you would query for all objects near a single location. So, to answer the question we need to understand the problem first.

Comment: Okay sorry for not explaining it enough. But basically, in Parse, I have an array of PFGeoPoints. I want a way to use the whereKey, nearGeoPoint, on those locations to establish which location is closest to me.